# Add context menu items to services (windows)

Tags: windows, services, context-menu, regedit, mmc

I am trying to a delete option to the right click menu of windows services, I know that you can do this with right click menus for files such as .cat / .bmp and I think you can here too, so I created the following:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Service\shell\Delete\Command]
@="sc.exe delete "%1\""

However when I check servics in MMC it still does not show up when I right click a service.

Perhaps I should be looking under HKCU/software/classes/

Any ideas how to get this right click option?
It will be useful as deleting services using the SC command is very picky with syntax and the service names.

The SC command should already reject any instructions to delete system services so I don't need to worry about that.

Comment: `HKCR\service` doesn't look like a context menu key to me. For example look at `HKCR\Folder` or `HKCR\http`. They both contain `shell` subkey by default, maybe also `DefaultIcon`, `shellex` or `ShellNew`. `HKCR\service` doesn't. I guess it's not what you think it is.

Comment: It is a COM object which is treated differently to a file or folder.
the key is for the object itself and in that key is options for the context menu.